# Prove that the bisectors of the 4 interior angles of a quadrilateral form a cyclic quadrilateral.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I can't seem to draw a good diagram for this question. I tried to draw a quadrilateral and draw the angle bisectors, but they intersected to form a very small quadrilateral. Then I tried to draw a cyclic quadrilateral and extend the sides to form an external quadrilateral, but the diagram turned out shoddy. A diagram and perhaps a starting point hint would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Letting the angles of original quadrilateral $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$, try to calculate the angles of small quadrilateral.

Comment: I know that much, but I need a nice diagram.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't help you with that. Try using some computer tool like GeoGebra if you want precise drawings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a nice diagram, a lousy one will do just as well
[image]

Let the angles of the original quadrilateral be $2\alpha,2\beta,2\gamma,2\delta$ so that $$\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\delta=180$$

So according to the diagram, the opposite angles in the small quadrilateral add to $180$

Comment: yeah I just did it with a bad diagram, different one from yours. Thanks for the answer though... :)